# are the ANY and the INNER JOIN statements same in this example?

Tags: sql

I'm recently learning SQL and I've faced this problem that I can't understand the difference between these two queries:
FIRST

```
SELECT ProductName 
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID = ANY (SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10);
```

SECOND:

```
select productname
from products
inner join orderdetails on orderdetails.productid=products.productid
where orderdetails.quantity = 10;
```

I tried both of the queries and got 2 different answers and still wondering what is the difference?

Comment: You're asking if two statmements are the same, or perhaps equivalent, but you already know they return different results - does that therefore not already answer it?

Answer (score 1):

The first one will only return a from the `Products` table *once*, no matter how many `OrderDetails` matches there are. The second will create pull the row from `Products` for **every** match in `OrderDetails`, including duplicating rows if needed.